# Parsing "…including a problem…, in a characteristically diffident aside, he noted his own 'fleeting vain attempts' to resolve it"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

**Prologue to a book which I was reading ends with this verbatim copy-pasted text:**

> > A book should be dedicated to someone living, so that the dedication can give pleasure. I have dedicated this book to my wife, who knows
> > very well how sincere that dedication is. There is a sense,   though,
> > not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in which this book most
> > properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, who, in a short life blighted
> > with much misfortune, gave to his fellow men so very, very   much of
> > everlasting  value—including a problem that continues to  vex them a
> > century and a half after, in a characteristically diffident aside, he
> > noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.
>
> John Derbyshire — [Prime Obsession: Bernhard Riemann and the Greatest Unsolved Problem in Mathematics](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Prime_Obsession/A-cg6DdryysC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=&pg=PT10&printsec=frontcover) *pub.* National Academies Press, 2003

I get what John Derbyshire wants to say, though I wonder whether there is something somewhat wrong with the third sentence, starting with "There is" & ending with "resolve it": I am unable to parse it satisfactorily.
**(The issue starts with the unexpected "he noted" , which seems jarring.)**

I could simplify it like this:

> There is a sense in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave to his fellow men so very, very much of everlasting value, including a problem that continues to vex them a century and a half after in a characteristically diffident aside he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

Parsing that requires simplifying further, though I have to make it 2 Sentences.

**Parseable Version 1 :**

> This book belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave a problem , in a characteristically diffident aside.
> He noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

**Parseable Version 2 :**

> This book belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave a problem.
> In a characteristically diffident aside, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

**Both are historically valid :**
Bernhard Riemann gave a Problem in a diffident aside.
Bernhard Riemann noted his attempts in a diffident aside.

Either way , the Original third Sentence looks ungrammatical & making it 2 Sentences makes it grammatical.

I have a third way to make it grammatical by adding a conjunction "and" between the 2 Sentences.

**Parseable Version 3 :**

> This book belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave a problem and noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

I have this last ( no more edits from my side !! ) fourth way to make it grammatical by making it a relative clause.

**Parseable Version 4 :**

> This book belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave a problem , for which he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” at resolution.

**Questions:**

Is my thinking right about the *original sentence* missing out a word or two (at least missing the conjunction) or somewhat mixing up the *structure*?
Alternately: Is there a way to *parse the original sentence* to show that it too is grammatically *correct*?

Comment: I think the problem stems from the "he noted..." clause. It's probably good to point that out, lest your question gets closed as requiring focus on something specific.

Comment: Are you still unable to parse it if you remove the parenthetical "in a characteristically diffident aside"? When trying to understand a sentence, eliminating parenthetical elements is a good approach. I don't see a problem with it, although it would be clearer had he put "in a characteristically diffident aside" after "he noted".

Comment: A simplification involves putting a full stop after 'value' followed by 'His legacy includes a problem that continues to vex mathematicians a century and a half after, in a characteristically diffident aside in one of his works, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.' The original is grammatical but unwieldy.

Comment: I have added that , @Joachim , though somebody has marked it for closure saying there are too many Issues here : It is Single Issue here !

Comment: I tried removing all the Parenthetical Elements , include that "aside" , @StuartF , though it was not working out. It will work out when I change that "aside" Parenthetical Element to a full stop.

Comment: Bernhard Riemann, [who, in a short life blighted with much misfortune,] **gave to his fellow men so very, very much of everlasting value**.//[there is no space before a colon in English].

Comment: Yes , It is my Contention that there are 2 Sentences improperly combined here , @EdwinAshworth , in line with your "A simplification involves putting a full stop ..." which will make it 2 Sentences.

Comment: No, the sentence, though long, is fine.

Comment: There is no comma splice here. Comma splices typically join two independent clauses.

Comment: For once, Lambie, I agree (with your last statement). Over-lengthy sentences are clunky, though, and acceptability includes more than grammaticality (as per Orwell's laws and Grice's maxims).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Some academic books like this do use long, complicated sentences. That just the way of the academic world.

Answer (score 2):

The parse is:

> There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in
> which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard **Riemann**, who [,
> in a short life blighted with much misfortune,] **gave to his fellow
> men so very, very much of everlasting value—including a problem that
> continues to vex them a century and a half after [,in a
> characteristically diffident aside,] he noted his own “fleeting vain
> attempts” to resolve it**.

Without parentheticals:
There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann who gave to his fellow men so very, very much of everlasting value—including a problem that continues to vex them a century and a half **after he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it**.

The sentence is fine.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time !! I realize what you are saying. I want to restate my Issue like this : Will it be okay to write this ".... including a problem , for which he noted his own attempts" ?

Comment: @Prem Why do that if it works the way it is? Anyway, you can't end it with "he noted his own attempts". :) You need the whole thing as I gave above. "after he noted" etc.

Comment: Oh boy, the dviers who are clueless. :)

Comment: Your "breakdown" doesn't work! Discard initial *There is a sense ... in which*, because so doing makes no difference to the syntactic validity of the remainder. Then, reversing your "bolding" for clarity, we've got *This book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, **[who, in a short life blighted with much misfortune,]** gave to his fellow men [a lot]*. If we suppose the bolded text there is "parenthetical", we should be able to simply remove it. But ***This book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann gave to his fellow men** [a lot]* is garbage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had left out the word "who",  which I have now put in. This book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann **who** gave to his fellow men to his fellow men etc.

Comment: That fixes my complaint, so have an upvote! I *do* think you're "more correct" than me insofar as you have ***a century and a half after*** referring to Riemann giving the aside, whereas my suggestion of simply starting a new sentence forces it to refer to when Riemann gave much to his fellow men ("credible", syntactically speaking, but pragmatically yours is the "correct" *intended* parsing).

Comment: ...you can have the upvote IF AND WHEN you take ***who*** out of the "parenthetical" element: *...Riemann, **who** [parenthetical] **gave...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was not in my parse without the parenthetical. You needn't be so strident for a typo.

Comment: I've upvoted, but even after your edit you still have the word ***who*** misleadingly in plain (not bold) type.

Comment: The problem did not vex men a century and a half after he wrote the aside, because the aside is *in* the paper; instead it is after he wrote the paper; "after" is not the conjunction here but the adverb, which is part of the clause "that continues…", not part of a would-be subordinate introduced by the would-be conjunction "after". It is not logical to take the aside in the paper as a time reference, when the matter that vexed Riemann's fellow men is what has been exposed in the paper. Think about asking since when this problem has vexed men. You are not going to say "since Riemann's aside".

Comment: @Lambie is correct and so (a little awkwardly) is the author! ***There is a sense, though, in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, who gave to his fellow men so very, very much of everlasting value—including a problem that continues to vex them a century and a half after*** *(in a characteristically diffident aside)* ***he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.*** ...I’d move *(in a characteristically diffident aside)* after *noted*.

Comment: @LPH — The problem continues to vex them a century and a half after he noted his own attempts to resolve it.

Comment: @TinfoilHat The sentence is correct grammatically, but from the point of view of pure meaning the interpretation of "after" as a conjunction produces something odd. (I should have written "*for** a century and a half" above in my comment.)

Comment: @LPH — There’s no problem with *after* as a conjunction here. If you remove the awkwardly placed aside (which happens to mention as aside), you can see that 150 years after Riemann noted his own fruitless attempts at solving the problem, the problem still vexes mathematicians.

Comment: @TinfoilHat There is no problem (it is grammatical) except for the fact that he made his remark in the very paper that exposed that problem (that what makes this  time reference odd, as I understand the sentence; the time reference to remember is actually that associated with the paper; although the two of them are the same, the association with the second event appears to blur an important fact that might even not be recovered subsequently  (minor problem on the level of efficient communication). I can see, certainly, that "50 years after Riemann noted his own fruitless attempts" is factual.

Comment: @LPH — Still not following you. Riemann gave mathematicians a problem that continues to vex mathematicians a century and a half after he noted his own vexation.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That is a truth, and this truth is what you read into the sentence, as written by the author, and the sentence is grammatical; I agree on all points. What I am arguing about is a point on the presentation of the information, which is not a part of grammar, but that grammar, more than occasionally, can be used to serve.

Comment: Nope. It's **after he noted his own "fleeting vain attempts" to resolve it**. You should just give in to this parse as it is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, who, in a short life
> blighted with much misfortune, gave to his fellow men so very, very
> much of everlasting value—including a problem that continues to
> vex them a century and a half after, in a characteristically diffident
> aside, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

There is no problem in parsing this sentence before the last part ("in a characteristically… resolve it").

- **1** There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue [*main clause*]

  - **2** **in which** [*sense*] this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann [*relative clause*]

    - **3** **who** [*Riemann*], in a short life blighted with much misfortune, gave to his fellow men so very, very much of everlasting value—including a problem [*relative clause* (embedded in preceding relative)]

      - **4** **that** [*problem*] continues to vex them a century and a half after [*relative clause* (embedded in preceding relative)]

**5** in a characteristically diffident aside, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

It appears that it is the "fleeting vain attempts" that are made in a "diffident aside"; that is, the sentence cannot be read as "the "problem is given in a diffident aside". Somehow the adverbial "in a characteristically…" is too far from the verb "give" for it to apply to the  clause of that verb.
Moreover, here is what the author says  in his work, "*Prime Obsession*" (p. 151).

> The 1859 paper “On the Number of
> Prime Numbers Less Than a Given Quantity” was Bernhard
> Riemann’s only publication on number theory, and the only one of
> his productions that contained no geometrical ideas at all.
> The paper, though dazzling and seminal, was in some respects
> unsatisfactory. There was, first of all, the great Hypothesis, which
> Riemann left hanging in the air (where it still hangs). His actual
> words, after making a statement that is equivalent to the Hypothesis,
> were
>
> > One would, of course, like to have a rigorous proof of this, but I
> > have put aside the search for such a proof after some fleeting vain
> > attempts (einigen flücht igen vergeblichen Versuchen) because it is not
> > necessary for the immediate objective of my investigation.

The aside is then *within* the paper consecrated by Riemann to the problem.
In consequence, the clause "in a char… it" is really an extrapolated clause within the extrapolated prepositional phrase "including…"; however, embeddings of extrapolated elements within other extrtapolated elements are not in use in English; that is the sentence would never be written as follows (also, the second dash is ambiguous: it can be read as the end of the extrapolated prepositional phrase).

> There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, who, in a short life
> blighted with much misfortune, gave to his fellow men so very, very
> much of everlasting value—including a problem that continues to
> vex them a century and a half after—in a characteristically diffident
> aside, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it——.

The author's sentence is deficient then in respect of the punctuation of the last part. An alternative that would keep the whole of the sentence a self contained unit consist in making the separation less interruptive by replacing it by a comma, and then using the m-dash after "after".

> There is a sense, though, not to be left unremarked in a prologue, in which this book most properly belongs to Bernhard Riemann, who, in a short life
> blighted with much misfortune, gave to his fellow men so very, very
> much of everlasting value, including a problem that continues to
> vex them a century and a half after— in a characteristically diffident
> aside, he noted his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The very last chunk should read

> —including a problem that continues to vex them a century and a half after he **had** noted, in a characteristically diffident aside, his own “fleeting vain attempts” to resolve it.

Comment: I don't think the past perfect is really necessary.

Comment: @Lambie The absence of the past perfect there contributed to the parsing issues people have had but it is not grammatically necessary.   Your own solution eliminates the parenthetical "in a characteristically diffident aside". Was that  elimination "necessary"?

Comment: I dunno, I think some people are just stubborn. :)